# Apply a calculation on all lines from a file

Tags: c#, file, line, streamreader

I'm stuck on a problem, I can not execute my calculation on all lines of my text file. The calculation only applies to the first line. I want to see my result in `richTextBox2`.

Here is my code :

```
using (StreamReader sr1 = new StreamReader(fileName))
{
    while ((line = sr1.ReadLine()) != null)
    {
        commands = line.Split(' ');
        if ((commands.Length > 1) && (commands[1].Contains('X')))
        {
            double X = Convert.ToDouble(commands[1].Substring(1, commands[1].Length - 1).Replace(".", ""));
            double Y = Convert.ToDouble(commands[2].Substring(1, commands[2].Length - 1).Replace(".", ""));
            Un = ((X * 100) / 1.57) / 1000;
            Deux = ((Y * 100) / 1.57) / 1000;

            richTextBox2.Text = "VM " + "M1=" + Un.ToString(".0") + " M2=" + Deux.ToString(".0");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I may not be totally clear on what you're trying to achieve, but it looks like you're replacing the text in richTextBox2 every time instead of concatenating.  If you're trying to make all of the results show, you might try making it += instead of just =.  Also, do you have a sample input file?

Comment: Try reading all the lines from the file first.  Typically, it is better to read in data quickly and close the file.

Comment: AS it was pointed out, you're assigning a new value on each iteration, instead of concatenating. However, the final result should be the last line which matched the "if" condition, not the first.

Comment: How can i apply the calculation to all the lines ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are assigning to your `richTextBox` new text in each iteration instead of appending it. Try this.

```
richTextBox2.Text += "VM " + "M1=" + Un.ToString(".0") + " M2=" + Deux.ToString(".0");
```

It is better to first read file and then assign it to `rictTextBox`. Like this.

```
string fileData = "";
using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(fileName))
{
     fileData  = sr.ReadToEnd();
}

StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
if (!String.IsNullOrEmptry(fileData))
{
   string[] splitedData = fileData.Split(new string[] { "\r\n" }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries); // Suppose file has delimited by newline

   foreach (string line in splitedData)
   {
       commands = line.Split(' ');
       if ((commands.Length > 1) && (commands[1].Contains('X')))
       {
           double X = Convert.ToDouble(commands[1].Substring(1, commands[1].Length - 1).Replace(".", ""));
           double Y = Convert.ToDouble(commands[2].Substring(1, commands[2].Length - 1).Replace(".", ""));
           Un = ((X * 100) / 1.57) / 1000;
           Deux = ((Y * 100) / 1.57) / 1000;

          sb.AppendLine("VM " + "M1=" + Un.ToString(".0") + " M2=" + Deux.ToString(".0"));
       }
   }

   richTextBox2.Text = sb.ToString();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You may want to use `StringBuilder` to build your `Text`. As others pointed out, you are overwriting the value of `RichTextBox's Text` property every line.
You may want to do something like this.

```
var sb = new StringBuilder();
using (StreamReader sr1 = new StreamReader(fileName))
{
    while ((line = sr1.ReadLine()) != null)
    {
        commands = line.Split(' ');
        if ((commands.Length > 1) && (commands[1].Contains('X')))
        {
            double X = Convert.ToDouble(commands[1].Substring(1, commands[1].Length - 1).Replace(".", ""));
            double Y = Convert.ToDouble(commands[2].Substring(1, commands[2].Length - 1).Replace(".", ""));
            Un = ((X * 100) / 1.57) / 1000;
            Deux = ((Y * 100) / 1.57) / 1000;

            sb.AppendLine("VM " + "M1=" + Un.ToString(".0") + " M2=" + Deux.ToString(".0"));
        }
    }
}
richTextBox2.Text = sb.ToString();
```

Answer (score 0):

If by "apply a calculation to all lines" you mean, log the calculation results for each line in the richBox, then you need to **concatenate** the new string, not assign a new one.

```
using (StreamReader sr1 = new StreamReader(fileName))
{
    while ((line = sr1.ReadLine()) != null)
    {
        commands = line.Split(' ');
        if ((commands.Length > 1) && (commands[1].Contains('X')))
        {
            double X = Convert.ToDouble(commands[1].Substring(1, commands[1].Length - 1).Replace(".", ""));
            double Y = Convert.ToDouble(commands[2].Substring(1, commands[2].Length - 1).Replace(".", ""));
            Un = ((X * 100) / 1.57) / 1000;
            Deux = ((Y * 100) / 1.57) / 1000;

            richTextBox2.Text += String.Format("VM M1={0} M2={1}", Un.ToString(".0"), Deux.ToString(".0"));
        }
    }
}
```

Also, you should use String.Format in cases such as this, it makes it more readable.